# Setting default drop down value dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Selecting a default value in the drop down that populates dynamically using json data.

Had tried using regCtrl.screeningTypeList[0], which is not helping.

```
<select ng-init="regCtrl.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId=regCtrl.screeningTypeList[0]" ng-model="regCtrl.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId" ng-change="regCtrl.getType(regCtrl.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId)"
                                 ng-options="sctype.screeningTypeId as sctype.screeningType for sctype in regCtrl.screeningTypeList"
                                 class="form-control field-size ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" name="screeningType"
                                 id="screeningType"  required >
                                <!--  <option value="">--SELECT--</option> -->
                                <!--  <option value="{{sctype.screeningTypeId}}">{{sctype.screeningType}}</option> -->
                              </select>
```

This is the angular js code for returning the json data.

```
function getScreeningTypeList(){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'master/getAllScreeningTypeMast'
            }).success(function(response){
                vm.screeningTypeList=response.result;
            }).error(function(resp){

            });
        }
```

controller other related code, which is defined in the beginning and this value is assigned to vm.

```
 RegistrationController.$inject = ['$http','LookupService','$filter'];
    function RegistrationController($http,LookupService,$filter){
        var vm = this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'master/getAllScreeningTypeMast'
        }).success(function(response){

            vm.screeningTypeList=response.result;
            vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId = vm.screeningTypeList[0];
        }).error(function(resp){

        });
```

AND remove ng-init on element,

Comment: Not working, giving this as selected <option value="?" selected="selected">

Comment: Getting this exception "Cannot set property 'screeningTypeId' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

You could try to give the value to your model after your http request.

```
function getScreeningTypeList(){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'master/getAllScreeningTypeMast'
            }).success(function(response){
                vm.screeningTypeList=response.result;

$scope.regCtrl.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId=vm.screeningTypeList[0];  // in your case i think you have to replace $scope by vm               
            }).error(function(resp){

            });
        }
```

Or try to put a function in your ng-init

```
Function nginitSelect(){
  $scope.regCtrl.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId= $scope.regCtrl.screeningTypeList[0]; // in your case i think you have to replace $scope by vm
}
```

Comment: Getting this exception "Cannot set property 'screeningTypeId' of undefined"

Comment: Try to inject $scope and use it to get access to your dom

Comment: vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId=vm.screeningTypeList[0]; tried and 
 
getting this exception "Cannot set property 'screeningTypeId' of undefined"

Comment: If you are doing a console.log of vm.user do you have any object

Comment: vm.user.screeningType=vm.screeningTypeList[0]; this worked, thanks